# Margin for enumerated environments

Tags: enumerate, paragraphs

[image: l]

How does one move out the "a)" so that the text in the enumerated environment aligns with everything else? Basically I want to produce text with default align alignment but where one is able to add alphabetic enumerations that do not interfere with the paragraphs; instead they should "float/hover" beside the paragraphs.

Answer (score 9):

The `enumitem` package provides ways to customize lists.  Specifying `leftmargin=0pt` will put the label in the margin:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[a),leftmargin=0pt]
\item Let us look at

  \begin{theorem}
    A test theorem.
  \end{theorem}

  \begin{proof}
    \lipsum*[1]
  \end{proof}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

If you wish all your enumeration enviroments to have this format, then you can write:

```
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{a),leftmargin=0pt}
```

in the preamble and just `\begin{enumerate}...\end{enumarate}` without having to specify options each time.

Comment: Thanks a heap! Why did we need "shortlabels"?

Comment: I just use `shortlabels` so I can specify the label as `a)` rather than `label=\alph*)`.